# Novel where frozen people from a lost civilisation are discovered in the arctic/antarctic

Tags: story-identification

Years ago (70's or 80's) I read a sci-fi novel.  It started with the discovery in the arctic (or antarctic) of a pair of humans (male and female) frozen in a block of solid helium.  When thawed out, they revive and tell a story of an ancient high-technology civilization (back when Gondwanaland existed I seem to recall).  This civilization had access to incredible energy sources having developed a grand unified theory of everything.

> In the end, they destroyed themselves in a conflict so huge that it shifted the earth on its axis.

Does anyone know what the novel was?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

How about [The Ice People](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ice_People_%28Barjavel_novel%29)?

*The Ice People (French: La Nuit des temps) is a 1968 French science fiction novel by René Barjavel.*

Comment: You nailed it !  Thanks much.  Can't believe I got a correct answer in only a couple of hours.

Comment: Not to rub it in, but it was an easy Google - "Gondwanaland ice novel". It does sound like an interesting story, may check it out. Thanks for the cleanup @OghmaOsiris

Comment: Thank you very much!!! I've been looking for that novel for years -also. Regards

Answer (score 2):

See my answer here :

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/28788/11672

This is certainly the story you remember.

Nicolas