# I'm looking for the name of a sci fi book

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for the name of a sci fi book, probably from the 1960s or 70s about a group of French & Am scientists who discover a dome under the ice in Antarctica

Comment: Are you certain that it was French and American, and specifically a dome (not a pyramid, for example)? [This other question and answers](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/28735/trying-to-recall-a-sci-fi-book-i-read-in-the-70s) sounds vaguely similar.

Comment: Can you add any more detail? In particular names are very helpful in jogging memories.

Answer (score 7):

There is a book called [The Ice People](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ice_People_%28Barjavel_novel%29) by *René Barjavel* that fits the little information you gave perfectly.