# Book from the 70's: advanced civilisation bodies found in Antarctica, one tells their story

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, telepathy, ancient-races

The book I'm looking for was set in either Antarctica or the North Pole.  I really believe it was Antarctica.  During a dig, 2 prehistoric, advanced civilization bodies were discovered.  One of them was still alive.  The main storyline is the live being is telepathically telling of their life and civilization.  It may have been a young adult Sci Fi novel.  I cannot remember the name or author.  I have been trying to search it out for months with no luck.  I would appreciate any help anyone can provide.

Comment: Dupe of [Novel where frozen people from a lost civilisation are discovered in the arctic/antarctic](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/5859/20774)?

Comment: @Richard Yep, that's how I found the answer too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Novel where frozen people from a lost civilisation are discovered in the arctic/antarctic](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5858/novel-where-frozen-people-from-a-lost-civilisation-are-discovered-in-the-arctic)

Answer (score 7):

[*The Ice People*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ice_People_%28Barjavel_novel%29), a 1968 novel by Rene Barjamel originally written in French.

> When a French expedition in Antarctica reveals the ruins of a 900,000 years old civilization, scientists from all over the world flock to the site to help explore and understand. The entire planet watches via global satellite television, mesmerized, as the explorers uncover a chamber in which a man and a woman have been in suspended animation since, as the French title suggests, "the night of time". The woman, Éléa, is awakened, and through a translating machine she tells the story of her world, herself and her man Païkan, and how war destroyed her civilization. She also hints at an incredibly advanced knowledge that her still-dormant companion possesses (who is not her love Païkan, but the scientist Coban, whom she hates), knowledge that could give energy and food to all humans at no cost. But the superpowers of the world are not ready to let Éléa's secrets spread, and show that, 900,000 years and an apocalypse later, mankind has not grown up and is ready to make the same mistakes again.

I found this by Googling "70s science fiction novel Antarctica past civilisation", which led me to [these](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5858/novel-where-frozen-people-from-a-lost-civilisation-are-discovered-in-the-arctic) two [previous](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/28735/trying-to-recall-a-sci-fi-book-i-read-in-the-70s) questions as the top two results.